# How to set starting zoom level in EsriImagery with datashader and bokeh?

Tags: python, data-visualization, holoviews, datashader, geoviews

I want to project a map with its starting position like this

[image: what i want]

The current output that I get is like this

[image: what I get]

```
import holoviews as hv
from geoviews.tile_sources import EsriImagery
from holoviews.operation.datashader import datashade, dynspread
import datashader as ds
import colorcet as cc

hv.extension('bokeh', 'matplotlib')

c = df.loc[(df['dropoff_latitude'] >= 40.5) &
           (df['dropoff_latitude'] <= 41) &
           (df['dropoff_longitude'] >= -74.1) &
           (df['dropoff_longitude'] <= -73.7)]

map_tiles  = EsriImagery().opts(alpha=0.5, width=900, height=480, bgcolor='black')
points = hv.Points(ds.utils.lnglat_to_meters(c['dropoff_longitude'], c['dropoff_latitude']))
taxi_trips = datashade(points, dynamic = True, x_sampling=0.1, y_sampling=0.1, cmap=cc.fire, height=1000, width=1000)

map_tiles * taxi_trips
```

I tried to set a zoom_level or  xrange, yrange in EsriImagery opts, but there are no such parameters. The method itself also has no documentation. And I couldn't find the documentation regrading this online too. (I could be looking at the wrong place.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

**Option 1 -- dircet input**

Set your wanted values using the parameter `x_range` and `y_range` in `datashade(...)`.

```
taxi_trips = datashade(points, x_range=(-8250000,-8200000))
```

**Option 2 -- indirect input**

If you don't know the needed values and you want to play around a bit, you can use this workaround.

The existing figure object has a [`Range1d`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/ranges.html?highlight=ranges#range1d) object, and this has a `start` and `end` point. This can be printed and set by a user.

This code starts with the last line of your example.

```
from bokeh.plotting import show

fig = hv.render(map_tiles * taxi_trips)
fig.x_range.start = -8250000
fig.x_range.end = -8200000
# fig.x_range.reset_start = -8250000
# fig.x_range.reset_end = -8200000
# the same for the y-axis
show(fig)
```

Here you have to get the bokeh (underlying package) figure and set your values. This values looks a bit odd and you maybe have to play a bit with it.

**Output for both options**

Here is the changed output.

[image: changed zoom]

I hope this works for you. Good luke.